# Merge duplicated cells instead of dropping them

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates, drop

I am trying to find a solution for the following issue I am having.
Suppose you have a dataframe with multiple columns - in this case two for easier explanation. Both columns do contain string data and no numeric data

```
COL 1   COL2
Mike    Test 1
Mike    Test 2
Mike    Test 3
```

What I would like to achieve is following

```
COL 1 COL 2
Mike  Test 1
      Test 2
      Test 3
```

I just need to drop the duplicates within the first column and leave the frame as it is.
Any idea how to do it?

Comment: What is the content of the dataframe cells you left blank? None? Empty string?

Comment: There is no merge, only replacement by empty string `df.loc[df['COL 1'].duplicated(), 'COL 1'] = ''`

Comment: works fine and thanks a lot. This really help
Is there also a way of merging the cells in Col1?